# How do I ignore comments with scan-sexps?

Tags: sexp

I have some lisp code that contains a comment:

```el
(while list
  ;; take the head of LIST
  (setq len 1))
```

I want to extract the positions of the sexps. I'm using `scan-sexps`. If I call `M-: (scan-sexps 12 1)` with the above code in a buffer, it returns 54, as expected.

However, if I try to do this programmatically:

```el
(setq src "(while list
  ;; take the head of LIST
  (setq len 1))")

(with-temp-buffer
  (insert src)
  (scan-sexps 12 1))
```

I get 22! This seems to be parsing the words in my comment. Why don't I get 54, and how do I fix this?

Reading the docstring for `scan-sexps`, it mentions `parse-sexp-ignore-comments`. However, this doesn't seem to affect the outcome:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert src)
  (setq parse-sexp-ignore-comments t)
  (scan-sexps 12 1)) ; still 22
```

How can I make `scan-sexps` return the end position of the next sexp, ignoring comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `with-temp-buffer` puts the buffer in a fundamental mode, and you are counting on it being in a Lisp mode, such as `emacs-lisp-mode`. So comments and sexps are not what you are expecting.

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  (insert src)
  (scan-sexps 12 1))

;; => 54
```

Comment: Aha, makes sense! Digging into this some more, it's the syntax-table (rather than e.g. `block-comment-start`) that `scan-sexps` needs.